# How to determine if an invariant rational function is defined at the $\theta$-polystable point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, quiver, geometric-invariant-theory

**Background:**

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional (associative and unital) algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume there is a quiver $Q=(Q_0,Q_1)$, where $Q_0$ is the set of vertices and $Q_1$ is the set of arrows, associated to $A$, i.e., $A\cong\mathbb{C}Q/I$, with $0 \neq I\subset \mathbb{C}Q$ an admissible ideal. Further assume that the algebra $A$ is such that the quiver $Q$ is acyclic.

For a dimension vector $\beta$, the representation space
$$\DeclareMathOperator\rep{rep}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}
    \rep_{\beta}(Q,I):=\biggl\lbrace M\in\prod_{a\in Q_1}\operatorname{Mat}_{\beta(ha)\times\beta(ta)}(\mathbb{C}) \;\bigg|\; \text{$M(r) = 0$ for all $r \in I$}\biggr\rbrace
$$parametrizes $\beta$-dimensional representations of $(Q,I)$.
The linear algebraic group
$$
    \GL_{\beta}:=\prod_{x\in Q_0}\GL_{\beta(x)}(\mathbb{C})
$$
acts on $\rep_{\beta}(Q,I)$ by change of basis.

**My setting:**

Now, I take an irreducible component $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\rep_{\beta}(Q,I)$ and restrict the action of $\GL_{\beta}$ to $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose I have a character $\chi$ of $\GL_{\beta}$ defined by the element $\theta\in\mathbb{Z}^{Q_0}$. Assume that there are two $\theta$-semi-stable representations $M,N\in\mathcal{C}$ (following the definition of A. D. King see [Moduli of representations of finite dimensional algebras](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esek/sem/stability/king.pdf)) and $\theta$-polystable representation $S\in\mathcal{C}$
such that we have one-parameter subgroups $\lambda_1,\lambda_2:\mathbb{G}_m\rightarrow \GL_{\beta}$ with $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\lambda_1(t)\cdot M=S\text{ and }\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\lambda_2(t)\cdot N=g\cdot S,\text{ for some }g\in\GL_{\beta}.$$ Also, assume that there exists a $G$-invariant rational function $h\in\mathbb{C}(\mathcal{C})$ such that $h\rvert_{\mathcal{O}(M)}=0$ and $h\rvert_{\mathcal{O}(N)}=1$.

**My question:**

> Is $h$ defined on the orbit of $S$? If not, is there any result which says when the invariant rational function will be defined on the limit, or is there any condition on $S$ or $\theta$ that guarantees that $h$ will be defined on the orbit of $S$?

Comment: Cross posted at math overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/437960/338456

Comment: since you are over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, you may not take the "limit" (in the sense of "analysis") when you speak of one parameter subgroups - can you explain what you mean in terms of algebro geometric constructions?

Comment: @hm2020 you're right. I have made the edits. I actually just copy-pasted the background material.